# Different email notifications (about pending posts) to different users

Tags: plugins, posts, user-roles, notifications

I looking for something like this: I have two (or more) groups of users. Each group is responsible to different person. So e.g. if someone from group A send draft, person responsible to group A get mail about it and can publish this post.

Sorry if something isn't clear. I can't find something like this.

Comment: Could you narrow down which emails verbatim you are talking about? WP sends quite a few of them.

Comment: I mean email about new pending posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('future_to_pending', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('new_to_pending', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('draft_to_pending', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('auto-draft_to_pending', 'send_emails_on_new_event');

/**
 * Send emails on event publication
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post
 */
function send_emails_on_new_event($post) {
    $emails = "email_1@mail.com, email_2@mail.com"; //If you want to send to site administrator, use $emails = get_option('admin_email');
    $title = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title($post->ID));
    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $message = "Link to post: \n{$url}";

    wp_mail($emails, "New post published: {$title}", $message);
}
```